# divs pushes down when usw float left

Tags: html, css

when i use float left in my inner divs they pushes down . i used clear:both bt not working. what to do??? it is also not possible using position absolute. i didnt face this kind of problem with float: left or float:right

css code:

```
.product-list{
    min-height:10px;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    top:35px;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:red;
}

.product-list-div{
    padding:0px;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color:navy;

}

.product-image-div{
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}


.product-details-div{
    width:200px;
    background-color: lime;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="product-list">
    <div class="product-list-div">
      <div class="product-image-div"></div>
      <div class="product-details-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in fiddle the problem is not showing. it behaves normal.. :(

Comment: try display block with the floated elements and display inlne-block with the parent element

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is customary to provide other people with a reproductible problem so we can actually fix them. If you can't, you probably do not pinpoint the right things :)

Comment: Wait, what... you were saying *"when i use float left"*  and then finally *" i didnt face this kind of problem with float: left or float:right"* huh? doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `product-list` div from your code. And also clear the floated divs, I have added `overflow: hidden` to `product-list-div`

```
<div class="product-list">
    <div class="product-list-div">
      <div class="product-image-div"></div>
      <div class="product-details-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>

product-list{
    min-height:10px;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    top:35px;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:red;
}

.product-list-div{
    padding:0px;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color:navy;   
     overflow: hidden;
}

.product-image-div{
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}


.product-details-div{
    width:200px;
    background-color: lime;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/SV99p/)

Comment: thanx it works for me.. now div's are not pushed down. but still they or not beside each other .. here is the fiddle 

http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/SV99p/

Comment: The `div's` are besides each other. You given a specific `width` and `height`to both the `div's`. Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/SV99p/2/. Here yellow and green `div's` are besides each other. You can increase the `width` and `height` as per your requirements.